# How do you make a custom audio filter using moviepy?

Tags: python, moviepy

I am trying to write my own custom audio filter for moviepy.

I am looking at audio_fadein as an example, but I am having trouble understanding the expected type of (t) the input variable.

Could anyone explain what the expected type of t is? Or where in the moviepy code I can look to see what libraries this t comes from or is used by? Thank you for any help, it is greatly appreciated.

```
@audio_video_fx
def audio_fadein(clip, duration):
   """Return an audio (or video) clip that is first mute, then the
   sound arrives progressively over ``duration`` seconds."""

    def fading(gf,t):
        gft = gf(t)

        if np.isscalar(t):
            factor = min(1.0 * t / duration, 1)
            factor = np.array([factor,factor])
        else:
            factor = np.minimum(1.0 * t / duration, 1)
            factor = np.vstack([factor,factor]).T
       return factor * gft
    return clip.fl(fading, keep_duration = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of t was an array of 2000 equidistant values.

These values were actually all times since the start of the clip, and the 2000 were just giving a window of times, presumably so that in the audio processing you could look at more values than just the current 'moment'.

This array case is handled by the 'else' clause. I am not sure when this function receives t as a simple scalar value.